# Interesting locus

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, locus

Consider an acute triangle $ABC$ and non-constant(*) point $P$ on $AB$. Take then points $D$ and $E$ on $AC$ and $BC$ respectively such that $\angle DPA=\angle EPB=\angle ACB$. Let $M$ be the intersection point, other than $P$, of the circumcircles of $\triangle APD$ and $\triangle BPE$. Find the locus of $M$

(*)I mean that P is moving on AB

Comment: Source of this problem, please?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $$\angle AMB =  \angle AMP + \angle PMB = \angle ADP + \angle PEB =\angle ABC + \angle BAC$$

Comment: How can I use this? Is this a sufficient condition for M to move in a circle that passes through A,B?

Comment: So the angle AMB is constant. Does that maybe mean that the circle passing through A,B,M will be also constant or something like that?

Comment: @Matheo Yes. Consider $M'$ a different point belonging to the same locus. Then angle $AM'B$ will be equal to angle $AMB$, so $M'$ sits on the circle that circumscribes triangle $AMB$.

Comment: @Matheo This is for $P$ on the segment $AB$. If $P$ is not on the segment, then you need to show that $AMB$ is constant equal to $ACB$.

Answer (score 4):

According to my experiments, that locus is a circle through $A$ and $B$.

[image: Figure]

Comment: I think only the arc of the red circle which lies on the same side of the line $AB$ as $C$ will be in the locus.

Comment: @Semiclassical: If you take $P$ on the *segment* $AB$ you are correct. Locus computation in Cinderella assumed the whole *line* $AB$, in which case you can get the whole circle.

Comment: You're quite right. (I let myself be fooled by an implementation error in Geogebra into thinking that only the segment AB would produce a valid intersection.)